# Magento 2 - Difference Between "Separately" and "Together" in Bundle Products

Tags: magento2.2, bundled-product

As I created a bundle product and **checked the difference between "Separately" and "Together"** by visiting/ordering this product in both condition but didn't find any difference.

Please visit here for more understanding:-

```
https://nimb.ws/UoiPIL

https://nimb.ws/f4r8yE
```

When I changed to **"Separately"** then I expected that on the cart/checkout page I'll get the option to choose individual shipping for each item( e.g- "1st T-shirt", "2nd T-shirt" etc) but not getting like that.both option seems same for me.

Here is the definition for both option:-

**1- Together**

Shipping together means that you can create one shipment for entire bundle items.

**2-Separately**

if you choose to ship bundle items separately, you need to notice when creating the shipment for each bundle item.

Please explain in detail so that I can understand well.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the products in the bundle are not located together it may be hard to ship them together. But if the items are of similar size/weight and fit in one box, you could cut down on shipping costs & time spent packaging the items.

If you want customers to have the option to choose different shipping methods for each item in the bundle, *I would assume* that the Separately option would be the best bet. If nothing changes on the checkout page, try to **flush the cache** or **reindex the indexer**.

Comment: Do we have the same shipping option for grouped product? Like option for together and separete

Answer (score 1):

Example: 
you added bundle product to cart. 
That product is 5 items
Shipping amount every items 5$

1- Together
Shipping amount is one item => 5$

2-Separately
Shipping amount is 5 items => 25$